# Why I get error when run two tests in Django APITestCase?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest, django-testing

I make tests for my API. When I run two tests I get error `apps.users.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.` in line `self.user = User.objects.get(pk=48)` on the *second test*. But if I run only one test, test is passed. What is the reason?

```
class MyTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user_data = []
        for i in range(1, 124):
            user_data.append({
                'email': 'first@mail.com'+str(i),
                'first_name': "firstname"+str(i),
                'last_name': "lastname"+str(i),
                'ip_address': "192.168.0."+str(i),
            })
        users = User.objects.bulk_create([User(**i) for i in user_data])
        self.user = User.objects.get(pk=48)   # I get error in this line

    def test_users_list(self):
        ...

    def test_users_pagination(self):
        url = reverse('users-list')
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
        response = self.client.get(url, {'users_count': 24, 'page': 2})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `setUp` is called before every test you define in the test case. What's happening is the first test runs setUp and creates users with `pk` values ranging from 1 to 123, and the second test creates users with `pk` values from 124 to 246, so there is no user with `pk=48`.

Try selecting the user based on another attribute like `email='first@mail.com48'`, and you should be good.

Comment: Thnx. But when I see `users[0].pk` or `users[0].id` after `bulk_create` I get `None`. When I see `users[0].email` I get correct `email` value. What is it?

Comment: I assume you're not using PostgreSQL, then. From the docs on bulk_create: If the model’s primary key is an AutoField [`bulk_create`] does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as save() does, unless the database backend supports it (currently PostgreSQL).